# jquery print does not include css or images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using jquery to print a specific div from a page:

```
var w = window.open();
var html = "<div id='directDepositFormPage' hidesidebar='true'>" + $('.printElement').html() + "</div>";

w.document.write(html);

//inject css onto page to print
$("head", w.document).append("<link href='static/com.redwage/widgets/directdeposit/css/default.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />");
$("head", w.document).append("<link href='static/com.redwage/widgets/directdeposit/css/SK2.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' media='print'/>");

w.print();
w.close();
```

Problem is when the page to print opens it does not contain any of the css or images from the page grabbed with jQuery.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: Adding styles directly seems to work, eg. $("head", w.document).append(" h3{ color:red; } "); while using links to add css does not.

Comment: Any 'live' example ? Have you tried injecting .css BEFORE w.document.write ?

Comment: what browser are you using?  if ie8 this won't work.

Comment: It's possible your CSS urls aren't valid relative to the document, but I can't possibly verify that without a live example.